# Very occasionally a user session is not deleted upon logout. Why might this happen?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, session-variables, express-session

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, Express-session, Redis, Digital Ocean Droplet

**Background:** My app allows users to log into and out of an account that they create.

**Problem:**  Perhaps 1% or 2% of the time when a user logs out the session is not destroyed and the user can get back to their myAccount page by simply browsing to it.  This only occurs on my Digital Ocean Droplet, never on my local Windows machine.  My Windows box is only used for testing and uses the default session store provided with express-session.

I can confirm with `redis-cli` that occasionally sessions are not destroyed.  For example just now,

```
$ redis-cli keys "*"
1) "sess:bVpK6dnOaMsF5ybU0fnnTsCXL14Y-fHh"
```

After logging out I ran `redis-cli` again and the session was still there.  Although I had been redirected to my home page I could browse to the myAccount page without logging in again.  I clicked log out and this time the session was destroyed and I could not browse to myAccount.

I should emphasize that this almost never happens.  The session is usually destroyed.  Why might this happen?

This is the setup for my droplet.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');

app.use(session({
    name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
    proxy: true;
    resave: true,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    unset: 'destroy',
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        secure: true
    }
}));
```

This is how I log users out.

```
router.get('/logout', redirectLogin, middlewareUserAccounts.logout);

exports.logout = wrapAsync(async function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        } else {
            res.clearCookie(process.env.SESSION_NAME);
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});  

exports.redirectLogin = wrapAsync(async function (req, res, next) {
    let doUserValuesExist = req.session.hasOwnProperty('userValues');
    if (doUserValuesExist === false) return res.redirect('/login');
    return next();
});
```

Comment: For starters, you should log any errors that `req.session.destroy()` sends to its callback.  That `throw new Error(err)` doesn't do anything useful because you're inside an asynchronous callback so it won't be caught by any of your code, not even the `wrapAsync()`.  Also, I would think you want to clear the cookie, even if `req.session.destroy()` has an error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Wow, as a Jr. dev maybe I'm missing an important concept.  Aren't all sync errors automatically caught by Express and sent to the error handler?  I thought wrapAsync could catch all Async errors and all sync errors would be caught automatically.

Comment: Nope.  A plain asynchronous callback like this one is called with an empty call stack so there's none of your code that can catch anything you throw there.  If you want to propagate errors, it would be better to promisify `req.session.destroy()` and then you could use `wrapAsync()` as intended to catch rejections or exceptions if you coded it correctly.  Just try putting a `throw new Error("hi")` inside a `setTimeout()` callback and see if you can catch that with a try/catch around the outside of the `setTimeout()`.  Hint: you can't.

Comment: In any case, this is probably a case where you'd rather log the error here and clear the cookie rather than let `wrapAsync()` handle the error any ways.  The intention is to logout and if you clear the cookie, you will achieve that.

Comment: @jfriend00 That version of my logout was just one of many.  I did have a version where res.clearCookie was called regardless.  And yet still even in this case the same non-logout error occurred.  So neither .destroy() nor .clearCookie() worked at the exact same time.  Does that narrow my problem down at all?  So it must be somewhere else?

Comment: If this code was always clearing the cookie, but you stayed logged in, then apparently this code wasn't getting called or `process.env.SESSION_NAME` was wrong or you weren't finishing the sending of the response (you have to send the response and the browser has to receive it for the cookie to get cleared).

Comment: `process.env.SESSION_NAME` is 100% correct.  So that means the code wasn't called.  `router.get('/logout', redirectLogin, middlewareUserAccounts.logout);` It must be in redirectLogin.  But for some reason the error never occurs on my desktop, only on linux.

Comment: Also, there could be timing issues.  The cookie is not actually removed from the browser's cookie store until it receives the response.  So, if you send some other request from the browser before this response gets back to the browser, the cookie will be sent with that 2nd request as it hasn't yet been removed from the browser's cookie storage.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated my question with the hook that runs before logout.  Is it possible that `redirectLogin` is creating a timing issue?  That starts to make sense.

Comment: I don't see anything timing related in the `redirectLogin` middleware.  It looks like it would throw if `req.session` is not present yet, but that wouldn't presumably be a normal path through the code as you'd have to be attempting to logout when you weren't logged in.  Still probably should defend against that.  Is the session middleware installed BEFORE all these other routes?

Comment: I just realized that on your computer where the problem never happens, you're not using redis as the session store.  That also points to a timing issue because the timing of session-related operations will be different with redis vs. the memory store.

Comment: @jfriend00 `app.use(session(...` is inside app.js and located above any of my endpoints which are called with `app.use(endpointsUserAccounts);` etc.  But you're right this has got to be a timing issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is there a way to wrap the code inside of my logout middleware in a Promise or something similar?  And then I don't get to the home page redirect until I absolutely know that the cookie and session are destroyed.

Comment: The `logout()` function already waits for the `req.session.destroy()` to finish before it redirects to the home page.  There is the other issue I mentioned about the `throw` if destroy fails. If you have ALL the code on github or something you can drop a link to, I can look through it for other things.

Comment: @jfriend00 After another 10 hours of testing and research I think I found my problem.  I used a GET request instead of a POST request for logout.  So when the browser used the cache instead of hitting the server it never went through the logout steps.  It just showed me the homepage from the cache and didn't really log out.  What a rookie mistake!!!!!  I'll fix it tonight.  I think/hope that was it.

Comment: Wow, good to know and glad you got it sorted.  I'd suggest you file your own answer that explains.  It seems that close examination of the Chrome debugger/Network tab or logging server-side in your `/logout` route might have been able to give you good clues.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's a good idea after I test the solution and get it working I'll answer my question.  I used the debugger but I wasn't experienced/clever enough to realize what I was looking at.  Neither the cookie in my browser nor the session in the DB was being deleted.  It wasn't until I started forwarding to different/odd pages that I realized what was happening.  [facepalm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of research and testing I discovered the source of my problem.

```
router.get('/logout', redirectLogin, middlewareUserAccounts.logout);
```

I used a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request.  Never use `GET` to log a client out of a server because `GET` may use the cache in the browser instead of hitting the server.  In my case `/logout` redirected to `/` after the session was destroyed.  Since `/` is in the cache it served that page up without hitting the server and the session was not destroyed.  The reason this wasn't a problem on desktop was because it wasn't using the cache for local files.  I'm not sure why this problem only occurred maybe 1% or 2% of the time on my Digital Ocean Droplet but that's the way it worked.